# Remote File Inclusion in JSON Data

Tags: .net, angular, security

I have an application built in angular and APIs are in .net .
When I check API through Postman it works properly,
but when I try same API with angular APP I got error like:

> Attack Category
> JSON Violations
> Detail
> attack_on="json-key" type="remote-file-inclusion-in-json" pattern="misc-commands" token="pwd" key="pwd

Example 2.

> Attack
> Remote File Inclusion in JSON Data
>
> Attack Category
> JSON Violations
>
> Detail
> attack_on="json-key" type="remote-file-inclusion-in-json" pattern="misc-commands" token="ID" key="ID"

Answer (score 0):

This might have nothing to do with Angular and could be a configuration issue on backend serving the response. Few things to be checked are:

1. Are you able to call the API using plain JS (through XHR API)?
2. Is the JSON data returned by API malformed?
3. You can use a mocking mechanism to mock API call. Try using it with the response returned by backend and check if it still fails.

Comment: Same Apps are working for other clients, But specific Client's firewall is restricting us, there is no issue with Get Calls, i am only having issue with POST, Moreover When i tried to call same POST API from postman ( Inside of server and outside from server ) postman is working but when same API called from Angular App it gives error